# My React JS website is not displaying all the images on the iPhone/iPad

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What can I do to work also good on IPhone/iPad? Thank you!

On MAC it works...

Here is the github url

The problem is one the shop page. The pics are png.

https://paulus1991.github.io/ecommerce/#/

Comment: In my iPhone XS it just working what is problem? :)

Comment: please check the shop page..and give me a feedback..

Comment: Oh, I see so what is your phone?

Comment: The phone I've tested is iPhone SE.. I have note 9...and is working perfect...

Comment: I've answer for you. And it is a little bit hard to understand platform rules. But I hope it can be helpful to you : )

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

I guess it is image size issue with iOS.
When I check your [website>shop] the image size is 1200 * 1200 pixel.
But There is some size rules in IOS. So, I think **your image file is too large to render in iOS**.

> The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels.

### Referecne

1. [iOS Image not appearing - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838212/ios-image-not-appearing)
2. [Resource Rules - iOS Document](https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW1)