# How to do PngCrush for my images of iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, image-optimization, pngcrush

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is PngCrush in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716303/what-is-pngcrush-in-ios)

I'm having a doubts about image optimisation technique of iOS apps **Pngcrush** 
My doubt is, 
Is pngcrush built-in to xcode or do we need to explicitly download pngcrush tool and optimise our images? 
If we want to do it explicitly how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This question may solve your problem: [Skipping the 'CompressResources' build step for XCode iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177160/skipping-the-compressresources-build-step-for-xcode-iphone-apps)

Another thing is there might chances that the PNGs are of type JPG's and the Extentation has been modified with png.