# What is PngCrush in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image-optimization, pngcrush

i know that Pngcrush is an image optimisation technique in iOS , but my doubt is does X-code will perform this internally during each build or before deploying our app to iTunes store we need to do this image optimization?

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If you have something to add, edit the original instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode does the conversion during build. The final app will have modified pngs, you don't have to do anything manually.

Comment: Are there any performance benefits by crushing images downloaded for in app use(such in uitableview)?

Comment: I suppose that's the reason they're doing it in the first place. They premultiply the alpha, so they don't have to do it at load time or at draw time; they swap the channels so the channel order is what I guess is the HW channel order, so they don't have to do that at load time either.

Answer (score 4):

The PNG crushing is done using the `pngcrush` tool which you can access manually with this command:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos pngcrush -iphone ...
```

Xcode will do this automatically for any files added to your target with the "PNG" file type:

[image]

If you include resources using a directory reference, the PNG crushing will *not* be performed by Xcode and you will have to do this manually.

You can crush all the PNGs in a directory manually using this little bash snippet:

```
find /path/to/directory -name "*.png" | while read filename; do
    xcrun -sdk iphoneos pngcrush -iphone "$filename" "${filename}_crushed"
    mv "${filename}_crushed" "${filename}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, XCode performs **automatically** the crunching.

You can control this behavior from your project's build settings:

Search for the setting "**Compress PNG Files**" and set the value you want.