# PNG images in Folder References are not pngcrushed when copied into bundle?

Tags: xcode, png, pngcrush

From reading building logs of Xcode, I noticed that for PNG images in Groups, command like this is run:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   -compress "" resource_folder_path/image.png app_bundle_path/image.png

However, for Folder References, there are no separate copy commands for PNG images under these folders, but only one copy command for each folder reference:

> builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude
>   .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks img_folder_path
>   app_bundle_path

Though I can't find the `builtin-copy` command(Can any one tell me where is it?), it seems it does not `pngcrush` PNG images. Is it true? If so, any good way to use Folder References to organize PNG images and  still let Xcode `pngcrush` these images when copying them into bundle?

Answer (score 1):

If you use folder references Xcode won't do the PNG crushing automatically and you'll have to do the optimisation manually instead. To manually run pngcrush in your folder you can use the bash snippet provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716625/646367):

```
find /path/to/directory -name "*.png" | while read filename; do
    xcrun -sdk iphoneos pngcrush -iphone "$filename" "${filename}_crushed"
    mv "${filename}_crushed" "${filename}"
done
```

If you don't like the command-line you can use an application like [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) instead.