# Is it possible to use PNGCrush within an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to build an iOS app that can select and compress images using PNGCrush. Is it possible to include this library inside an iOS app? How would this be done?

Comment: Follow this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716303/what-is-pngcrush-in-ios

Comment: Not at all my intent. I'm looking to make an app. From the app, select a PNG from a Document Provider, say from Transmit, and then compress it with PNGCrush.

Comment: Assuming you have the source, there should be no issue with using it.  How to do so is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: @Avi PNGCrush is open-source. Could you direct me to a tutorial or something that would show me how to use it within or embed it within an iOS app?

http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/

Comment: I don't know of one, and such a question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: What exactly is inappropriate about my question?